# javascript: how to create a function that receives any number of arguments and take average depending on the num. of arguments?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, average

I wanted to create a function that receives any number of arguments and take average depending on the num. of arguments. So I tried the code as below;

```js
function takeAvg(...nums) {
 return nums.reduce((total, curVal) => {
  return (total + curVal) / nums.length;
 });
} 
console.log(takeAvg(10, 20)) // returns 15 - no problem
console.log(takeAvg(10, 20, 30)) // returns 13.333333333333334 weirdly.
```

I think the problem is with nums.legth but I did not understand why? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: just move `/ nums.length` after reduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're dividing each partial result of the summation with the length, instead of only the final result.

```js
function takeAvg(...nums) {
    return nums.reduce((total, curVal) => {
        return (total + curVal);
    }) / nums.length;
} 

console.log(takeAvg(10, 20)) // 15
console.log(takeAvg(10, 20, 30)) // 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
function takeAvg(...nums) {
 return nums.reduce((total, curVal) => {
  return (total + curVal)
 }) / nums.length;;
} 
console.log(takeAvg(10, 20))
console.log(takeAvg(10, 20, 30))
```

## You asked why

In the previous case you do :

```js
function takeAvg(...nums) {
     return nums.reduce((total, curVal) => {
        return (total + curVal) / nums.length;
   });
} 


x = ((10+20)/3 + 30)/3 // take average of 10,20,30

console.log('maths expression : ',x)
console.log('your function : ',takeAvg(10,20,30))


x = ((((10+20)/4 + 30)/4) + 40)/4 //take average of 10,20,30,40

console.log('maths expression : ',x)
console.log('your function : ',takeAvg(10,20,30,40))
```

and now:

```js
x = (10 +20+ 30)/3
console.log(x)
```